# word boundary RegEx JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches a string that starts with a capital letter and contains at least one lowercase after it. BUT without other symbols before or after the word.

*Example:*
I have this string :
'**Explore results $With$ the Tools TTools  -Below%.**'

I want to take only: Explore and Tools.

I wrote this regex: **/\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b/g** ;
But it doesn't help me, because matches and words with symbols ($,%,-) before or after them.
How can I get rid of them ?

Comment: Yes, use whitespace boundaries, `(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-z]+(?!\S)`, or `(?:\s|^)([A-Z][a-z]+)(?!\S)` to extract Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can we use `\b(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-z]+\b` or `(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-z]+\b`

Comment: No idea, but `\b(?<!\S)` = `(?<!\S)` here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot!                                                                                               I have another question if you can help me :)                                                               
How to add something as a condition logical or (||).                                                      
The string must be valid if it ends with space OR comma and nothing else.

Comment: Maybe `[ ,]$`...